# MySQL: return count of several items for each row

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table that lists some items.
Then I have 3 different tables that each record various actions done against an item, along with a date and who did it:

```
Table "items":
item_id, title, description

Table "item_views":
item_id, date, user_id

Table "item_follows":
item_id, date, user_id

Table "item_likes":
item_id, date, user_id
```

I am trying to come up with a query that would list each item, along with how many times they are referenced in each of the other 3 tables.

It needs to only count the actions that are between two given dates, and I also need to be able to order by any of the counters.

So I would give it two dates and say "order by likes", and it would return something like this:

```
item id     item title     views_counter    follows_counter      likes_counter
item1       Some title     0                5                    6
item2       Some title     4                0                    4
item3       Some title     3                2                    0
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join to subqueries which find the counts:

```sql
SELECT
    i.item_id,
    i.title,
    COALESCE(v.view_cnt, 0)   AS views_counter,
    COALESCE(f.follow_cnt, 0) AS follows_counter,
    COALESCE(l.like_cnt, 0)   AS likes_counter
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS view_cnt
    FROM item_views
    GROUP BY item_id
) v
    ON v.item_id = i.item_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS follow_cnt
    FROM item_follows
    GROUP BY item_id
) f
    ON f.item_id = i.item_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS like_cnt
    FROM item_likes
    GROUP BY item_id
) l
    ON l.item_id = i.item_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for! It gave me the flexibility to add all sorts of other filtering and sorting too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select i.*,
       sum(which = 'view') as views,
       sum(which = 'follow') as follows,
       sum(which = 'like') as likes
from items i left join
     ((select item_id, 'view' as which
       from item_views
      ) union all
      (select item_id, 'follow' as which
       from item_follows
      ) union all
      (select item_id, 'like' as which
       from item_likes
      )
     ) vfl
     on i.item_id = vfl.item_id
group by i.item_id;
```

Comment: Urghh, left join multiple nested group by is much better IMO

Comment: @charlieface why?

Comment: @Strawberry Granted I don't know that much about how MySQL optimizer works, but SQL Server would have a hard time with that. It may go as far as unioning the tables before the join, and/or forcing a nested loop (as opposed to a hash or a merge), whereas the left join syntax in the other answer would not have the same issues. Plus it just doesn't look as good to me aesthetically (personal opinion)

Comment: @Charlieface . . . Your comment is absolutely not true.  SQL Server, in fact, works much better with this `union all` version if the outer query is filtered on columns in the subqueries.  The optimizer is smart enough to project the filters into the subqueries *before* doing the `union all`.

Comment: Usually yes it will push the predicate down, but it can do the same thing with the left join / group by syntax also, IME that syntax is more easily transformable by the optimizer. The summing is also less performant here as you need to check each row for which sum to add it it to, whereas the left join pushes the summing down below the join. You could perhaps optimize your version still, by grouping within each unioned table.

Comment: @Charlieface I'm confused. "Usually yes" is quite a different position from "have a hard time with that"

Comment: @Strawberry Usually yes, but it doesn't always work, so it has a harder time with it than `left join / group by`, which is very well understood by the optimizer. I might point out also, that I often see on [so] people using `union` instead of `union all` in this context, and that can really screw things up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! I ended up going for Tim's answer as it gave me some 
 flexibility for additional filtering and sorting (this one probably does too, but I found it easier with the other one)